# SQL Server Count items available

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a pretty simple inventory items database that will allow me to check out items between dates. I will need to return a single row that will tell me the available, reserved, and total inventory of this item. I cannot seem to get this correct.

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @startDate AS DATE
DECLARE @endDate AS DATE
DECLARE @partID AS INT
SET @startDate = '4/15/2015'
SET @endDate = '4/25/2015'
SET @partID = 248

SELECT COUNT(ii.[PartId] WHERE ii.[PartStatus] = 1 ) AS [Available],
       COUNT(ii.[PartId] WHERE ii.[PartStatus] = 2 ) AS [Reserverd],
       COUNT(ii.[PartId] WHERE ii.[PartStatus] <> 4 ) AS [TotalInventory],
FROM ShipListInventory.dbo.InventoryItems AS ii
LEFT JOIN ShipListInventory.dbo.InventoryItemCalendars AS iic   
     ON iic.[ItemId] = ii.[Id]
WHERE iic.[StartDate] NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  AND iic.[InboundDate] NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  AND ii.[PartId] = 248
COMMIT TRAN
```

EDIT: I am only returning rows from `InventoryItemCalendars`I want to return items from `InventoryItems`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItems](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PartSatuts] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [PartId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Barcode] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [PicturePath] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [Notes] [NVARCHAR](1000) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.InventoryItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItems]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryItems_dbo.Parts_PartId] FOREIGN KEY([PartId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Parts] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryItems_dbo.Parts_PartId]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [InboundDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectNumber] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Project_Id] [INT] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.InventoryItemCalendars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryItemCalendars_dbo.InventoryItems_ItemId] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[InventoryItems] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryItemCalendars_dbo.InventoryItems_ItemId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryItemCalendars_dbo.Projects_Project_Id] FOREIGN KEY([Project_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryItemCalendars_dbo.Projects_Project_Id]
GO

INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItems]([PartSatuts],[PartId]) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItems]([PartSatuts],[PartId]) VALUES(2,1);
INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItems]([PartSatuts],[PartId]) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItems]([PartSatuts],[PartId]) VALUES(4,1);


INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars](StartDate,InboundDate,Project_Id, ItemId)VALUES('1/1/2015', '4/15/2015',1,1)
INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars](StartDate,InboundDate,Project_Id, ItemId)VALUES('1/1/2015', '4/15/2015',1,1)
INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars](StartDate,InboundDate,Project_Id, ItemId)VALUES('1/1/2015', '4/14/2015',1,2)
INSERT INTO ShipListInventory.[dbo].[InventoryItemCalendars](StartDate,InboundDate,Project_Id, ItemId)VALUES('1/1/2015', '4/15/2015',1,1)
```

this isnt returning  data from correct table it is only returning data form `InventoryItemCalendars` which isnt what i want. i want it to only use this to check the dates. it should return the items from `InventoryItems` table

Comment: So what is the problem, beside using `WHERE` in the `COUNT`? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: i have editied question above

Comment: That still isnt enough. We need db schema, sample data and expected output. Read the link I provide so you get tips on how improve your question.

Comment: sure, i will edit.

Comment: Also be specific what is the problem, because your query have several sintaxis error. But looks like you are asking for a fix on what data to bring. In case of error, include any error message.

Comment: I have attached the 2 tabels in question here. also a bit of sample data

Answer (score 2):

Here is a syntactically correct version:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ii.[PartStatus] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Available],
       SUM(CASE WHEN ii.[PartStatus] = 2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Reserverd],
       SUM(CASE WHEN ii.[PartStatus] <> 4  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalInventory]
FROM ShipListInventory.dbo.InventoryItems ii LEFT JOIN  
     ShipListInventory.dbo.InventoryItemCalendars AS iic   
     ON iic.[ItemId] = ii.[Id]
WHERE iic.[StartDate] NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND
      iic.[InboundDate] NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND
      ii.[PartId] = 248;
```

There is no transaction when you do a select, so committing is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ii.[PartStatus] =  1 THEN ii.[PartId] END) AS [Available],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ii.[PartStatus] =  2 THEN ii.[PartId] END) AS [Reserverd],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ii.[PartStatus] <> 4 THEN ii.[PartId] END) AS [TotalInventory]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Juan Carlos I have found the correct answer.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN  ii.[PartSatuts]=1 THEN ii.[PartId] END ) AS [Available],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN  ii.[PartSatuts]=2 THEN ii.[PartId] END ) AS [Reserverd],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN  ii.[PartSatuts]<> 4 THEN ii.[PartId] END ) AS [TotalInventory]
FROM ShipListInventory.dbo.InventoryItems AS ii
LEFT JOIN ShipListInventory.dbo.InventoryItemCalendars AS iic   
     ON iic.ItemId = ii.Id
WHERE ((iic.StartDate NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  AND iic.InboundDate NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
  OR iic.InboundDate IS NULL)
  AND ii.PartId = 248
```